# Get information from external microsoft teams user in callrecords from ms graph api

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to get the email from an external teams call participant?

The data is retrieved from `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions`

I resolve our ids with the graph user enpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}`

I am writing the callrecords into our ticketing system and would like to display the email from an participant from a different tenant.

```
[participants] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [acsUser] => 
                [spoolUser] => 
                [phone] => 
                [guest] => 
                [encrypted] => 
                [onPremises] => 
                [acsApplicationInstance] => 
                [spoolApplicationInstance] => 
                [applicationInstance] => 
                [application] => 
                [device] => 
                [user] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => myId
                        [displayName] => Nico Bleiler
                        [tenantId] => myTenant
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [acsUser] => 
                [spoolUser] => 
                [phone] => 
                [guest] => 
                [encrypted] => 
                [onPremises] => 
                [acsApplicationInstance] => 
                [spoolApplicationInstance] => 
                [applicationInstance] => 
                [application] => 
                [device] => 
                [user] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => externalId
                        [displayName] => External User
                        [tenantId] => hisTenant
                    )

            )

    )
```

As far as i know i can not query a user which is not in my tenantId.
But is there a way i could atleast retrieve his email?

Comment: You can use list participants to get the list of participants from a given call. Being said that i dont remember there is a way exists at this point to get email address of Microsoft teams user.

Comment: Being said that i remember two closest uservoice items for this - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37577683-need-api-to-get-chat-participants, https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41642644-add-a-property-for-the-external-or-guest-users-ema - go ahead, upvote them - so that Microsoft can consider implementing it.

Comment: I upvoted it. For now i just label the external user as unkown as this is still better than no information

Comment: Glad that you did so!!

Comment: I will move this to answer. So it can be useful to others, they can upvote as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list participants to get the list of participants from a given call. Being said that i dont remember there is a way exists at this point to get email address of Microsoft teams user. Being said that i remember two closest uservoice items for [uservoice1](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37577683-need-api-to-get-chat-participants), [uservoice2](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41642644-add-a-property-for-the-external-or-guest-users-ema)- go ahead, upvote them - so that Microsoft can consider implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe i used the `userPrincipalName` property to get out emails.

`GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}` which can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http